# How to combine 2 SegmentedTimelines in 1?

Tags: java, jfreechart, timeline

As in documentation it is said:

"

```
/**
     * Factory method to create a 15-min, 9:00 AM thought 4:00 PM, Monday
     * through Friday SegmentedTimeline.
     * <P>
     * This timeline uses a segmentSize of FIFTEEN_MIN_SEGMENT_SIZE. The
     * segment group is defined as 28 included segments (9:00 AM through
     * 4:00 PM) and 68 excluded segments (4:00 PM through 9:00 AM the next day).
     * <P>
     * In order to exclude Saturdays and Sundays it uses a baseTimeline that
     * only includes Monday through Friday days.
     * <P>
     * The <code>startTime</code> of the resulting timeline will be 9:00 AM
     * after the startTime of the baseTimeline. This will correspond to 9:00 AM
     * of the first Monday after 1/1/1900.
     *
     * @return A fully initialized SegmentedTimeline.
     */
     public static SegmentedTimeline newFifteenMinuteTimeline()
```

"

in code of this method is:
"`timeline.setBaseTimeline(newMondayThroughFridayTimeline());`"

and if you just search where the `SegmentedTimeline baseTimeline`

is used, you will see, that is uesed in 3 other methods:

`public void addBaseTimelineException(long domainValue)` - which adds some exception to baseTimeline,

`public void addBaseTimelineExclusions(long fromBaseDomainValue,
                                          long toBaseDomainValue)` - same here, and

`public SegmentedTimeline getBaseTimeline()`.

Note that this getter is not used anywhere else.

So my question is, where is implementation, that allows to add weekends as an exceptions to segmentedTimeline, which is above baseTimeline?
Summary: Adding baseTimeline to any timeline does nothing.

How to modify that class (SegmentedTimeLine) to make a timeline, which is sth like intraday - but monday to friday, and every day from 9.00am to 7.00pm?

Comment: I know, that, I can add aweekends exception list to my i.e. segmentedtimeline = new SegmentedTimeLine(HOUR_SEGMENT_SIZE, 8, 16), which starts on Mon, at 9.00am, but if we have, 3 years of data, there is a decrease in performance.

Comment: "but if we have, 3 years of data, there is a decrease in performance." - sorry, my bad, my renderer (CandlestickRenderer) was set "setAutoWidthMethod(CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST);" and this gives decrease of performance :/

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation issue with the SegmentedTimeline that's still not fixed and (worse) might not get to be fixed soon. The [project leader said](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=116507) he might do away with this feature or implement a new one in the future JFreeChart versions.

As a suggestion, a CategoryAxis-based chart might help you display the dataset without having to worry about excluding long (non-trading time segments), although you might need to override some methods to customize the display of the domain axis. See http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html